# .net web tables with same row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am programmatically creating tables for a web page in ASP.Net.  Basically I am running a SQL query and selecting data to be used as part of different tables on this page.  Sometimes the same data is used in multiple tables.

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
/* ...
    assign cells to row
*/
table1.Rows.Add(row);
table2.Rows.Add(row);
```

The row in table 1 becomes corrupted in some way.  It won't display during debuging.  Not an empty cell, just nothing.

I put a watch on the the first cell of the new row of table1 to check the value after creation; and immediately following being added to table1 it looks good. As soon as I step over adding row to table2 the watch pane says

[The value of this expression may be incorrect.  It could not be evaluated because: "new System.Linq.SystemCore_enumerableDebugView(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow)new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(table1.Rows).Items[4].Cells).Items[0]' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException]

I believe this has something to do with objects being sent by reference rather than by value, but I don't see why this is causing a problem.  The TableRow class doesn't have a copy or clone routine to use.  I've also tried putting my data in TableCell[] and moving that into TableRow at the last minute, but this hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableRow` derrives from `System.Web.Control` indirectly, via `WebControl`.  A control keeps a direct reference to it's parent, of which it can only have one.  When you add the row to `table2` you are implicitly removing it from `table1`.

If you look at the source for the `TableRowCollection` type, which is what `Table.Rows` is, you'll see that the `AddAt` method contains the line: `this.owner.Controls.AddAt(index, row);`   That, effectively, makes the `TableRow` a child control of the last `Table` to which it was added.

The cells of the table work much the same way.  To avoid this, you'll have to create a new `TableRow` instance with new cells to hold your data.  I didn't find a native method to do a deep copy of a TableRow, so you're likely to need to write one on your own.

Comment: I was afraid of that